# Node MSSQL Incorrect Date Value is being Inserted

Tags: sql-server, node.js, tedious

I am having some issues inserting a date value. I'm importing data from a DB2 server into a SQL 2016 server and although I can insert the records the date is displaying as the following format

0001-01-01

I also have this deprecated warning telling me to use date which, I believe I am.

[image]

Here is my code. I've tried formatting the date to YYYY-MM-DD and even to YYYYMMDD but nothing seems to fix the issue.

```js
table = new sqlDB.Table('tempInsert')
table.create = false
table.columns.add('District',sqlDB.VarChar(100),{nullable: true})
table.columns.add('Alias',sqlDB.VarChar(100),{nullable: true})
table.columns.add('Account',sqlDB.VarChar(10),{nullable: true})
table.columns.add('ShareID',sqlDB.VarChar(4),{nullable: true})
table.columns.add('EffDate',sqlDB.Date,{nullable: true})
table.columns.add('ExpDate',sqlDB.Date,{nullable: true})

for(i = 0; i < data.districts.length;i++){

    table.rows.add(
        data.districts[i].DISTRICT,
        data.districts[i].ALIAS,
        data.districts[i].ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
        data.districts[i].ID,
        moment(data.districts[i].EFFECTIVE_DATE).format('yyyy-MM-dd'),
        moment(data.districts[i].EXPIRATION_DATE).format('yyyy-MM-dd')
    )

}
```

And my sql table. just so you can see it is a date field.

```js
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tempInsert](
 [District] [varchar](100) NULL,
 [Alias] [varchar](100) NULL,
 [Account] [varchar](10) NULL,
 [ShareID] [varchar](4) NULL,
 [EffDate] [date] NULL,
 [ExpDate] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Temporary solution is just to use a text field, values went in as it should and I'll just have my SP handle the conversion.

Comment: If anyone finds a solution i'd love to see it.

Comment: Dates have **no** format. They are binary values, just like decimals, integers and bits. How those binary values are displayed is up to the *client*. SSMS, your application or any other client is still a client. SSMS uses the `YYYY-MM-DD` unless you change it from options because it's not dependent on culture. That doesn't change the underlying value

Comment: Why did you use `.format('yyyy-MM-dd')` at all if the data comes as a `date` from DB2? The other question would be why go through Node? You can use SSIS or the Data Import wizard in SSMS (it's the same thing) to move data from any source to any other, including DB2 to SQL Server. You can also set up DB2 as a linked server on SSIS and query it directly.

Comment: `the date is displaying as the following format 0001-01-01 ... I've tried formatting the date to YYYY-MM-DD` but this *is* in the YYYY-MM-DD format. Are you saying you get a `0001-01-01` **value**? That's the zero value for dates which means that the data was inserted as a *zero*, not even null. Check your source data and the results of `moment(data.districts[i].EFFECTIVE_DATE)` and `moment(data.districts[i].EFFECTIVE_DATE).format('yyyy-MM-dd')`. They may be empty strings, ie zeros,ie 0001-01-01

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format:
`moment(data.districts[i].EFFECTIVE_DATE).format('YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. *Specifying* a format forces a conversion to string then back to date which isn't only slow, it can lead to incorrect data if different formats are used for the two steps